# AngularJS ui-router subpages

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm new to ui-router and I'm trying to add a class to my navigational items if it's the active page.

Here's my stateProvider:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
    })
    .state('matches', {
        url: '/matches',
        templateUrl: 'templates/matches.html',
    })
    .state('matches.add', {
        url: '/add',
        templateUrl: 'templates/add-match.html',
    })
    .state('statistics', {
        url: '/statistics',
        templateUrl: 'templates/statistics.html',
    });
```

Which should translate into the following structure:

```
/home
/matches
    /add
/statistics
```

I'm generating my navigation using a controller:

```
app.controller('mainNavController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [
        {
            title: 'Home',
            sref: 'home',
            href: './home',
        },
        {
            title: 'Matches',
            sref: 'matches',
            href: './matches',
        },
        {
            title: 'Statistieken',
            sref: 'statistics',
            href: './statistics',
        },
    ];
}]);
```

Which generates the `ul.main-nav` like this:

```
<ul class="main-nav" ng-controller="mainNavController">
    <li ng-repeat="item in items" ui-sref-active="is-active"><a href="{{item.href}}" ui-sref="{{item.sref}}">{{item.title}}</a></li>
</ul>
```

The normal (root level) elements get the correct active class, but when going to `/matches/add` it doesn't add the active class to the `Matches` element in my navigation.

How would I go about doing this? I checked out [this commit](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/commit/bf163ad6ce176ce28792696c8302d7cdf5c05a01) but I'm not seeing how I could implement this into my project.

Comment: Please provide controller code & markup for the case of 2-level menu

Comment: There is no 2-level menu. The only way to get to `/matches/add` is to click a button: `<a ui-sref="matches.add" class="button">...</a>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will work, if you place `ui-sref` for second-level items under first-level items

Cite from official [angular-ui-router docs](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref-active):

> `ui-sref-active` can live on the same element as `ui-sref` or on a parent
>   element. The first `ui-sref-active` found at the same level or above the
>   `ui-sref` will be used.

Comment: So what I'm trying is not possible at all? I don't want to place it under the first-level item...

Comment: it is not possible via ui-sref-active, but it is actually possible programmatically, for example via `ng-class="getRightClass()"`

Comment: I'll do it that way then, thanks for the explanation :)

Comment: Alexei, any idea on how the `getRightClass` function would look? I guess I need to use the `$state` object but I'm not sure how to do this...

Comment: $scope.getRightClassFor = function (state) {
   var currentState = $state.current.name;
   if (currentState.indexOf(state) !== -1) {
       return 'active';
   } 
   return '';
}

Comment: Yeah, that's the part I could figure out. I want to know how to check if the class has to be added. I suppose I have to use the `$state` object provided by ui-router but I'm not quite sure how to check the current state etc.

Comment: My previous code example should be used as <li class="{{getRightClassFor(stateName)}}" ui-sref="...">...</li>

Comment: It didn't state the contents of the function when I first read your (second) comment... I'll try it out later! Thanks for the help, anyways :)

Answer (score -1):

Seems like if you update your ui-router to the latest version this is taken care of